# iw does not recognize wlan1

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless

Seems a simple issue, but drives me crazy the entire day.
Situation: raspbian RaspBerry 3 b with external USB wifi dongle (Atheros based). Need to use this instead of the inbuilt wifi.

- Both interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) are detected by `iwconfig` and `ifconfig`.
- Both interfaces are perfectly usable.
- I get something useful on `sudo iw dev wlan0 info`
- But I can't get the hell anything then `unknown device (-19)` for the same command on wlan1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but out of curiosity... why not use the built in one?

Comment: I need to use MONITOR mode, which is not supported by the internal ifc. But the problem is solved. Purchased another adapter and all problems where gone. The problematic adapter was a TP-TN722N v2 (which was wrong at all). The working is a CS 300

Answer (score 1):

To give this question an answer, here is the solution the OP posted in his comment:

> I need to use MONITOR mode, which is not supported by the internal ifc. But the problem is solved. Purchased another adapter and all problems where gone. The problematic adapter was a TP-TN722N v2 (which was wrong at all). The working is a CS 300